# Why am I getting string reversal wrong with a trailing space character?

Tags: c++, string, reverse

I am unable to get why there is a space and it is getting me wrong.

**Below is the code I wrote for the solution**

Why there is blank space char at the end of the string at the end even after reversing my string.

[Question](https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-remove-to-make-valid-parentheses/)

```
class Solution {
public:
    string minRemoveToMakeValid(string s) {
        string str = "";
        int n = s.length();
        int open=0;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            if(s[i]=='('){
                open++;
            }else if(s[i]==')'){
                open--;
                if(open<0){
                    open=0;
                    continue;
                }
               
            }
            str+=s[i];
        }
        open=0;
        string s2="";
        for(int i=n-1;i>=0;i--){
            if(str[i]==')'){
                open++;
            }else if(str[i]=='('){
                open--;
                if(open<0){
                    open=0;
                    continue;
                }
                
            }
            s2=s2+str[i];
        }
        
       reverse(s2.begin(),s2.end());

        return s2;
    }
     
};
```

[Leetcode Submission getting wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPvGz.png)

Comment: the leet code problem description does not mention reversing the string. Did you link the right problem?

Comment: yeh, I just reversed it becz it was reversed while traversing once in backwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The length of `str` may be less than one of `s`, but you are using the length of `s` while iterating within `str`. You must use correct length.

```
        string s2="";
        n = str.length(); // add this
        for(int i=n-1;i>=0;i--){
```